# How can I send a SignalR message from an Azure Function without using Azure SignalR Service

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, signalr

I have an older C# app that is being migrated to the cloud. It uses SignalR, but only direct client/server connections. No SignalR service is involved yet.

I am extracting some processes that are well suited for an Azure function, but one feature I would prefer to not have to redesign for this MVP is a SignalR message back to the user that tells them the percent complete for this job.

I am reading the MS documentation from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service-output?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp focusing on Isolated-Processes.

I can see how I can send messages to the Azure SignalR service, but I am unclear how I might be able to just send a message back to the caller.

I would really like to set up a simple Hub and send messages directly to the client as the function progresses.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest giving web pub sub a look?  Microsoft has a good comparison article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-web-pubsub/resource-faq#how-do-i-choose-between-azure-signalr-service-and-azure-web-pubsub-service).  Summary, it is a bit more language agnostic, and if you're already using azure then it has less setup overhead than SignalR.

https://dev.to/albertbennett/how-to-azure-pubsub-service-2ccb